# Dynamically uniform expressions with nested for loops in GLSL

Tags: glsl, shader, vulkan

In GLSL, the for loop counter is dynamically uniform if it is initialized with, compared against, and incremented by dynamically uniform expressions:
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression

This shader has nested for loops:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject
{
    int x;
} ubo;

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ubo.x; i++)
    {
        // 'i' is dynamically uniform, because ubo.x is dynamically uniform

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            // is 'j' dynamically uniform?
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand, 'j' is dynamically uniform, because it is compared to 'i', which is also dynamically uniform. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All other things being equal, `j` will be dynamically uniform.

Comment: "ceteris paribus"